# Vue.filter is not calling while HTML rendering

Tags: vue.js

I am new to Vue.js

While rendering the html, I am invoking a Vue.filter. It should show a date in another format.

Below is my js file :

```
  var details = new Vue({
  el: '#ajax-article-detail',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
  },
  methods: {
   showName: function() {
        console.log('Calling showName...'); 
        return 'Im Event';
   }
  }
});

      Vue.filter('parseDate', function(date, format) {
      if (date) {
        //console.log(moment(String(date)).format(format));
        return moment(String(date)).format(format);
      }
      });
```

and in html, I am calling like `{{${start_date} | parseDate('ddd, Do MMM YYYY')}}`

and as a response, I am getting same statement.
means, I am getting `{{${start_date} | parseDate('ddd, Do MMM YYYY')}}` as it is in html.

Can anyone please suggest what I did wrong ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your code by adding the filter property within the Vue component creation.

```
  var details = new Vue({
  el: '#ajax-article-detail',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
  },
  methods: {
   showName: function() {
        console.log('Calling showName...'); 
        return 'Im Event';
   }
  },
  filters: {
    parseDate: function(date, format) {
      console.log('value passed: ' + date); //check the browser console if it is passed
      if (date) {
        //console.log(moment(String(date)).format(format));
        return moment(String(date)).format(format);
      }
    }  
});
```

Then use the filter like this-

```
{{2018-12-19 16:46:00 | parseDate('<your_date_format>') }}
```

However, you need to check if you are passing the value correctly. Try passing some hard coded string value first and check the console window.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I have tried the above js. But still output is showing same.

Comment: {{'2018-12-19 16:46:00' | parseDate('ddd, Do MMM YYYY')}} I have hardcoaded the date like this

Comment: One more point I have to mention is, I am using FTL for html generation.

Comment: @Venu I think you are using the filter incorrectly. I will update my answer. Also, can you tell me what is the date format you are passing and have you checked it if it really formats the date in plain JavaScript?

Comment: My actual date is 2018-12-19 16:46:00 , and I am going to convert something like -- Wed, 19th Dec 2018.

Comment: Even showName method is also not invoking. I am not getting the console log

Comment: @Venu Is your Vue component getting compiled and rendered properly? Try re-building the Vue project and refresh the browser. I usually use npm build and VS code for this. You can also install Vue dev tool plugin in your browser to debug more about the problem. For Chrome- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd?hl=en

Comment: I haven't installed Vue. I just included vue.min.js in my html page